# Difference vs Previous Row & DistinctCount

Tags: powerquery

I want to calculate a Delta Weeks column in Power Query WeekNum[current row] - WeekNum[previous row]

I found a way to do it using the [Index] column, but it is painfully slow, and my table is 100k rows.

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Customer", type text}, {"Product", type text}, {"WeekNum", Int64.Type}}),

#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Delta Weeks", each try Source[WeekNum]{[Index]} - Source[WeekNum]{[Index]-1} otherwise 0) in #"Added Custom"
```

Also, after this, I need another column who would count the distinct values from the beginning up to that row.

Most of the weeks are consecutive, so basically the distinct count will increase when they are not.

(I don't know how to do this in Power Query).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe PQ wasn't designed for working with previous row context.

What I did find works better than referencing the previous row using [Index]-1, is creating 2 index columns (one starting with: 0,1,2, and the other with 0,0,1,2, so basically an [Index]-1 floored at 0), and then joining the 2 tables, which basically puts the previous row on the same row, if that makes sense.

However even that was too slow for me, and in the end I implemented a different approach, and I simply use a bit of VBA code where I calculate the difference via previous row, and then import the table in PQ. I think this is a more efficient (and considerably faster) approach!

Answer (score 0):

try/otherwise might be pretty slow. Is it any faster if you use `if [Index] > 0 then Source[WeekNumber]{[Index]} - Source[WeekNumber]{[Index] - 1} else 0` for the custom formula?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your try ... otherwise code I would use something more direct like:

`[WeekNumber] - #"Added Index"[WeekNumber]{[Index] - 1}`.

Then I would add a Replace Errors step to clean up the first row.